# Join and unpivot on multiple tables

Tags: sql, join, unpivot

I have two tables:

Correction table:

```
C_CORRECTIONS
CorrAmount  |HalfYear1  |HalfYear2  |Type   |REFNUM |
-----------------------------------------------------
1000        |50         |50         |HYINT  |R123   |
```

Collected Table:

```
P_COLLECTED
Amount      |Type   |Account    |REFNUM |
-----------------------------------------
1500        |TOTAL  |ACCT1      |R123   |
50          |HYINT  |ACCT2      |R123   |
50          |HYINT  |ACCT3      |R123   |
```

What I need is:

```
CorrAmount  |Type   |Account    |REFNUM |
-----------------------------------------
1000        |TOTAL  |ACCT1      |R123   |
50          |HYINT  |ACCT2      |R123   |
50          |HYINT  |ACCT3      |R123   |
```

I have tried below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.AMT, P.ACCOUNT,C.REFNUM FROM (
SELECT U.AMT, U.Type, REFNUM
FROM C_CORRECTIONS
UNPIVOT
(
  AMT
  FOR INT_AMT IN (CorrAmount,HalfYear1,HalfYear2)
) U
) C
LEFT JOIN P_COLLECTED P
ON C.REFNUM = P.REFNUM AND C.AMT = P.Amount;
```

Result:

```
AMT     |ACCOUNT    |REFNUM |
--------|-----------|-------|
50      |ACCT2      |R123   |
50      |ACCT3      |R123   |
1000    |           |R123   |
```

Edit: Okay. So i have used left join instead of join, and put in distinct and i get main amount, but i cannot seem to get the account for it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You unpivot C_CORRECTIONS and then join P_COLLECTED to it.

But perhaps you could start from P_COLLECTED and join C_CORRECTIONS to it.
Since P_COLLECTED already has the multiple rows.

Test example:

```
declare @P_COLLECTED table (Amount int, Type varchar(8), Account varchar(8), REFNUM varchar(8));
declare @C_CORRECTIONS table (CorrAmount int, HalfYear1 int, HalfYear2 int, Type varchar(8), REFNUM varchar(8));

insert into @P_COLLECTED (Amount, Type, Account, REFNUM) values
(1500,'TOTAL','ACCT1','R123'),
(50  ,'HYINT','ACCT2','R123'),
(50  ,'HYINT','ACCT3','R123');

insert into @C_CORRECTIONS (CorrAmount, HalfYear1, HalfYear2, Type, REFNUM) values
(1000,24,26,'HYINT','R123');

select 
(case when t.Type = 'TOTAL' then c.CorrAmount else t.Amount end) as Amount,
t.Type, t.Account, t.REFNUM
-- , c.*
from @P_COLLECTED t
left join @C_CORRECTIONS c 
      -- on (t.REFNUM = c.REFNUM and t.Type in ('TOTAL',c.Type));
      on (t.REFNUM = c.REFNUM and t.Type = 'TOTAL');
```

Comment: That works perfectly!! Thank you.. also, the actual query is a lot complex and has a join of 5 huge tables. Is there any alternative to case? To reduce the time taken by the case function.

Comment: @Anu a CASE works on row level, so doesn't impact the query plan, so doesn't take more time.  And if REFNUM is a primairy key in C_CORRECTIONS, that extra left join shouldn't make your complex query slower. But maybe you noticed that this query also joins t.Type on c.Type.  If you only need to correct the TOTAL amount, you can simplify it to `ON (t.REFNUM = c.REFNUM and t.Type = 'TOTAL')`.

Comment: thanks.. just realised even HalfYear1 and HalfYear2 will be changed(50 to 25 in this case).. i will need to make corrections table as base..

Answer (score 1):

Hi I have modified in your script please verify

```
Select  Amount, 
        Type,
        'Acct' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY  Refnum  ORDER BY (Select  NULL))AS VARCHAR(20))Account,REFNUM 
                from  
            (Select Amount, Type, REFNUM from  @Table2 where type = 'Total'
                    UNION ALL
            SELECT C.AMT, C.Type,C.REFNUM FROM (
            SELECT U.AMT, U.Type, REFNUM
            FROM @Table1
            UNPIVOT
            (
              AMT
              FOR INT_AMT IN (CorrAmount,HalfYear1,HalfYear2)
            ) U
            ) C,@Table2 P
            WHERE C.REFNUM = P.REFNUM OR  C.AMT = P.Amount
            GROUP BY C.AMT, C.Type,C.REFNUM)T
```